# Pac's file URL, how to retrieve a query param value in FindProxyForURL function

Tags: proxy, query-string, pac

How can I read query param value of PAC's file URL inside FindProxyForURL function?

For example:
my pac file url: ....../proxy.pac?port=8082

I'd like to be able to get a port value in FindProxyForURL function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.

You should dynamically generate PAC file in your PAC server per the query param value.